# Mysql Searching with ANDs and ORs

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use for searching in database similar query to this:

`SELECT * , MATCH (field1, field2) AGAINST ('".$keyword."') AS score FROM table_name WHERE MATCH (field1, field2) AGAINST etc...`

But when user writes in search box more than one word, it gives all results which are either first word or the second.

Basically, what I want to do, is allow people to search like this:

`(keyword1 OR keyword2) AND keyword3` and similar. So, it would find `keyword1` and `keyword3` or `keyword2` and `keyword3`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have a full-text search index on your table, you could instruct that the match should run in boolean mode (you should prob. double check the syntax in the mysql documentation).

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH('+keyword1 +keyword2 keyword3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Keyword prepended with the '+' sign are mandatory (i.e. returned records must contain both),  keywords without '+' matches in OR mode, so the above query is equivalent to (keyword1 && keyword2) || keyword3

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string and run 2 different queries or join your queries.

SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE MATCH (keyword1 AND keyword3)

SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE MATCH (keyword2 AND keyword3)

or you can write something that joins these results.

I really hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

adds several operators to weight results like:

- require certain keywords (+ must be in result)
- exclude keywords (- can't be in result)
- negative value (~ can be in result, but will lower results with this word)
- favor one word over another (< and >)
- grouping (parenthesis)
- wildcard (*)
- Literal strings ("quoted string" matches exactly that and not each word individually)